# No module named QtMultimedia On Mac Os 10.11

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4, qt5, pyqt5

System deployment:

```
Mac Os 10.11.6
Xcode 8.0
python 2.7.10(system builtin)
Qt5.4.1
Qt5.7.1
sip4.16.7
PyQt-gpl-5.4.1.tar.gz
qmake path is point to Qt5.4.1
```

Traceback:

```
>>>import PyQt5.QtCore
>>>import PyQt5.QtMultimedia
ImportError: No module named QtMultimedia
```

QtMultimedia.so is already in "*/site-packages/PyQt5" directory.

It seems i have installed correctly and it works well when i import PyQt5.QtCore. Is there anyone knows why i can't import PyQt5.QtMultimedia?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to uninstalled Qt5.4.1, Qt5.7.1, Xcode8.0 and reinstalled Qt5.4.1 with Xcode7.3.1.

Then it works well when i type "import PyQt5.QtMultimedia" in the bash.

The main reason seems to be the differences between Xcode8.0 and Xcode7.3.1.

If someone knows it, you can make my answer complete.

Thanks all the same.